# How to fix NOVIABLEICE error in EasyRTC?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, easyrtc

EasyRTC no longer seems to work at all, even the demo page gives NOVIABLEICE error (only works inside personal network): https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/demo_audio_video.html

So solutions may be:

1. All EasyRTC stun servers are down?
   Easyrtc options (including stun server):
   https://easyrtc.com/docs/server-api/easyrtc_default_options.js.php

   I tested the Google stun server here, I get nothing: Selecting "iceTransport" value "relay" it returns nothing. I don't really understand how this testing is working or not working. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

(this option is not true)

2. Our network providers are now using hard firewalls, since 2018?
   (This means I need a turn server now in 2018?)

So do I have any options in 2018? (worked before in 2017).

(turn server does not solve it, or does it? read below)

I can not find any more information about this issue. Can I get this app updated or are my apps relying on EasyRTC useless.

I have added my TURN server like this if there should be a firewall (the wrong place):
(credentials aren't real)

```
var myIceServers = [
  {"url":"stun:213.114.16.203:443"},
  {
    "url":"turn:213.114.16.203:443",
    "username":"test",
    "credential":"123456"
  },
  {
    "url":"turn:213.114.16.203:443?transport=tcp",
    "username":"test",
    "credential":"123456"
  }
];
```

Turn server seems to be working fine also tested with the mentioned above app. Tested with a free TURN/STUN server I found: numb.viagenie.ca:3478.

All works in this demo: https://demo.xirsys.com/ it seems to be using TURN server.

Some turn servers are probably not complete, needs more further investigation.

FINALLY SOLUTION:

Edit `easyrtc_default_options.js` (`option.appIceServers`) and add your TURN/STUN servers there, because `myIceServers` may not work (add STUN servers the same way as above).

You need to add SSL/TLS (certs for turn/stun) to make it work in Chrome (`turnserver.conf`) get real ones by Letsencrypt (install the bot) and activate "`realm`" in conf + set the certs locations that should be it.